# Package pgfkeys Error(s)

Tags: pgfplots, errors, pgfkeys

I am searching for a solution of 5 package pgfkeys errors. I think the root of the problem is the same. Preliminary I tested if the pgfplot version is the same I have installed (v1.13) and I used in my code (compat=1.13).
My tex-code:

```
    \listfiles
    \documentclass[ngerman]{standalone}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
    \usepackage{environ}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{sistyle}
    \SIstyle{German}
   %============================================================================

    \begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[title={Paris Plot ElastomerXY},title style={text width=8cm,font=\tiny},ylabel={$dc/dn$ in \SI{}{mm/cycle}}, xlabel={$T$ in \SI{}{N/mm}}, legend style={cells={anchor=west}, legend pos=north west, tiny}, xmin=0.45, xmax=2.5, ymin=1E-6, ymax=0.01]
    \pgfplotstableread{Daten/T_10A_x.dat} \datatable 
    \addplot[green!60!black, mark=triangle*,only marks] table[x index=3, y index=5] {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{Data of Mrs X};
    \addplot[green!60!black, mark=triangle, only marks] table[x index=9, y index=11] {\datatable};
        \addlegendentry{Data of Mr Y};
    \addplot[green!60!black, mark=none,domain=0.52:2.09,samples=100]{6.1876E-5*x^1.38671};
    \addplot[green!60!black, dashed, mark=none,domain=0.53:2.03,samples=100]{8.23473E-5*x^1.3867};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

The errors:

```
    ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/width', to which you passed '4cm', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
    ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/height', to which you passed '', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
    ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/max space between ticks', to which you passed '12', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
    ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/major tick length', to which you passed '0.1cm', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
    ! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/minor tick length', to which you passed '0.066cm', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I would be grateful for a solution.

Supplement:

T_10A_x.dat

```
    PK  MWE1    STABWE1 MT1 STABT1  MDCDN1  STABMDCDN1  MWE2    STABWE2 MT2 STABT2  MDCDN2  STABMDCDN2
    2   0.052799144 0.002363125 0.521654964 0.071112212 1.6302E-05  4.38245E-05 0.046990654 1.774E-03   0.527688702 nan 6.706E-05   7.2824E-05
    3   0.05332986  0.002374846 0.640799468 0.145810547 1.77546E-05 4.92628E-05 0.046085321 0.001678041 0.66021389  nan 5.22514E-05 5.35509E-05
    6   0.055023074 0.002286157 0.854679167 0.140646074 7.48306E-05 0.000243076 0.045130508 0.002649089 0.732226449 nan 7.34344E-05 5.33923E-05
    4   0.09842756  0.003199639 1.161353193 0.164903611 6.86283E-05 0.000108369 8.518E-02   0.003124106 1.187725754 nan 9.8963E-05  6.86056E-05
    5   0.097294229 0.003299059 1.143703583 0.178297552 8.41961E-05 0.000117132 0.084425    0.002596193 1.320494764 nan 9.3594E-05  7.50381E-05
    10  0.093909204 0.003743834 1.086642855 0.1553737   5.42785E-05 0.00011677  0.081561765 2.839E-03   1.181484578 nan 7.72386E-05 4.29831E-05
    12  0.159165529 0.008062109 2.093146892 0.599052547 0.000153294 0.000163905 0.13522 0.004191062 1.956414847 nan 0.000195847 0.000100594
    13  0.154518522 0.008613584 1.806539562 0.758680826 0.000124254 0.000161388 0.133773171 0.003791242 2.038E+00   nan 0.000213969 0.000287621
    14  0.146225517 0.009956112 1.850506661 0.552970808 0.000186329 0.000167609 0.125442105 0.00538561  1.802407552 nan 0.000231828 8.97119E-05
```

As result I get:

[image]

But I can not ignore the errors if I use more plots in a article environment.

Comment: can you include some part of your data (a few rows)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the way, the problem comes from the fact that, `pgfplots` has predefined styles to quickly scale the plots such as `normalsize, tiny, small, footnotesize` and so on. Here, the axis options leaked to the legend where the key family is TikZ but the keys are `pgfplots` keys. Hence the error.

```
/pgfplots/tiny/.style={
    width=4cm,
    height=,
    legend style={font=\tiny},
    tick label style={font=\tiny},
    label style={font=\tiny},
    title style={font=\footnotesize},
    every axis title shift=0pt,
    max space between ticks=12,
    every mark/.append style={mark size=6},
    major tick length=0.1cm,
    minor tick length=0.066cm,
    every legend image post/.append style={scale=0.8},
},
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    legend style={cells={anchor=west}, legend pos=north west, font=\tiny}
```

instead of

```
    legend style={cells={anchor=west}, legend pos=north west, tiny}
```

This solution works.

Thanks @percusse